# My the simple reinforcement learning model doesn't learn. I don't know why

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I am a beginner in programing on tensorflow and reinforcement learning. I have made simple program with reinforcement learning algorithm. To be more exact, I’ve recomposed the example program from book “Hands-On-Reinforcement-Learning-With-Python” by Sudharsan Ravichandiran.

I’ve taken next example:
https://github.com/sudharsan13296/Hands-On-Reinforcement-Learning-With-Python/blob/master/08.%20Atari%20Games%20with%20DQN/8.8%20Building%20an%20Agent%20to%20Play%20Atari%20Games.ipynb

This example is building an agent to play Atari game Pacman using Deep Q Network. In my program I’ve kept DQN-algorithm and changed the model and state vector.
Now the agent is car in 2-D plane. It begin motion in position x=1000, y=1000. According my thoughts Car must travel to position with coordinates x=0, y=0.
I set rewards as function f=1/(x1^2+y1^2) - 1/(x0^2+y0^2), where (x0,y0) is the previous position of the car and (x1,y1) – the next position of car. So if car is traveling to position (0,0) the rewards are increasing.

The state vector has only 4 dimension: [ x,y,sin(fi),cos(fi) ], where x, y are the two coordinates of car and fi is the angle of car in 2-D plane. The car has actions. It can turn right or turn left or move in the same direction.

As you can see, this is very simple model. But the DQN-algorithm doesn’t learn. It cannot find the good policy and car doesn’t travel to position (0,0).

I want to ask the specialist on reinforcement learning to run my simple program in python and find out the problem in this very simple program.

```
    import math
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    import tensorflow as tf2
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
    from tensorflow.compat.v1.layers import dense
    from collections import deque, Counter

    fi = np.float(0)
    xx = np.float(0)
    yy = np.float(0)
    V = np.float(1)
    MaxAbsAction = 0.1;

    N = 1000;
    x_Data = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float)
    y_Data = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float)
    i_D = int(0)

    def ModelReset():
        global fi, xx, yy, x_Data, y_Data, i_D    

        fi = np.float(0)
        xx = np.float(1000)
        yy = np.float(1000)
        i_D = int(0);
        x_Data[i_D] = xx
        y_Data[i_D] = yy

        obs = np.array([xx,yy,math.cos(fi),math.sin(fi)],dtype=np.float)    
        return obs 

    def ModelStep(action):
        global fi, xx, yy, x_Data, y_Data
        global MaxAbsAction, i_D, V, N

        PreviousDistance = math.sqrt( xx*xx + yy*yy )

        if action > MaxAbsAction:
           action = MaxAbsAction

        if action < -MaxAbsAction:
           action = -MaxAbsAction

        fi += action
        xx += V * math.cos(fi)
        yy += V * math.sin(fi)
        i_D += 1
        x_Data[i_D] = xx
        y_Data[i_D] = yy

        NextDistance = math.sqrt( xx*xx + yy*yy )    
        reward = (1/NextDistance - 1/PreviousDistance)
        next_obs = np.array([xx,yy,math.cos(fi),math.sin(fi)],dtype=np.float)        
        done = i_D>=N-1 or NextDistance < 20
        return next_obs, reward, done 

    n_outputs = 3

    def n_to_float_action(n):
        global MaxAbsAction
        return -MaxAbsAction + 2*MaxAbsAction/(n_outputs-1)*n

    def Q_Network(X, name_scope) :

        initializer = tf.keras.initializers.VarianceScaling()    

        with tf.variable_scope(name_scope) as scope:
            fc1 = dense(X, 100, kernel_initializer=initializer, 
                       activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid)

            fc2 = dense(fc1, 100, kernel_initializer=initializer, 
                       activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)

            output = dense( fc2, n_outputs, 
                       kernel_initializer=initializer )

            Q_vars = {v.name[len(scope.name):]: v for v in 
                      tf.get_collection(key=tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, 
                                        scope=scope.name)} 
           return Q_vars, output   

    epsilon = 0.1
    eps_min = 0.01
    eps_max = 1
    eps_decay_steps = 5000000 

    def epsilon_greedy(action,step):
        
        p = np.random.random(1).squeeze()
        epsilon = max(eps_min, eps_max-(eps_max-eps_min)*step/eps_decay_steps)
        
        if np.random.rand(1) < epsilon:
            return np.random.randint(n_outputs), epsilon
        else:
            return action, epsilon    
        
    def sample_memories(batch_size):
        if exp_buffer_full:
            size_buff = exp_buffer_length
        else:
            size_buff = exp_buffer_pos
            
        perm_batch = np.random.permutation(size_buff)[:batch_size]
        mem = exp_buffer[perm_batch]
        return mem[:,0],mem[:,1],mem[:,2],mem[:,3],mem[:,4]    

    num_episodes = 100000
    batch_size = 200
    learning_rate = 0.001
    X_shape = (None,4)
    discount_factor = 0.97

    global_step = 0
    copy_steps = 10000
    steps_train = 40
    start_steps = 2000
    logdir = 'logs'

    exp_buffer_length = 1000000
    exp_buffer_pos = 0;
    exp_buffer_full = False
    exp_buffer = np.zeros(shape=(exp_buffer_length,5), dtype=object)

    tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=X_shape,name='X')
    in_training_mode = tf.placeholder(tf.bool,name='in_training_mode')

    mainQ, mainQ_outputs = Q_Network(X,'maimQ')
    targetQ, targetQ_outputs = Q_Network(X,'targetQ')

    X_action = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None,),name='X_action')
    Q_action = tf.reduce_sum(
        targetQ_outputs * tf.one_hot(X_action, n_outputs),
        axis=-1, keep_dims=True )

    copy_op = [tf.assign(main_name,targetQ[var_name]) 
               for var_name, main_name in mainQ.items() ] 
    copy_target_to_main = tf.group(*copy_op)

    y = tf.placeholder( tf.float32, shape=(None,1), name='y' )
    loss = tf.reduce_mean( tf.square(y-Q_action) )

    optimazer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
    training_op = optimazer.minimize(loss) 

    loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar('LOSS',loss)
    merge_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
    file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir,tf.get_default_graph())

    train_loss = None

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init.run()

        for i in range(num_episodes):
            done = False
            obs = ModelReset()
            epoch = 0
            episodic_reward = 0
            action_counter = Counter()
            episodic_loss = []
            
            while not done:
              
                actions = mainQ_outputs.eval (
                    feed_dict={X:[obs], in_training_mode:False}) 
                    
                action = np.argmax(actions,axis=-1)
                action_counter[str(action)] += 1

                action, epsilonn = epsilon_greedy(action, global_step)
                
                next_obs, reward, done = ModelStep(n_to_float_action(action))      
                        
                exp_buffer[exp_buffer_pos,:] = np.array([obs, action, next_obs, reward, done],dtype=object)
                
                exp_buffer_pos += 1
                if exp_buffer_pos >= exp_buffer_length:
                    exp_buffer_pos = 0
                    exp_buffer_full = True            
                
                if global_step % steps_train == 0 and global_step > start_steps:
                    o_obs, o_act, o_next_obs, o_rew, o_done = sample_memories(batch_size)
                    
                    o_obs = [x for x in o_obs]
                    o_next_obs = [x for x in o_next_obs]
                    
                    next_act = mainQ_outputs.eval( 
                        feed_dict={X:o_next_obs,in_training_mode:False}) 
                    
                    y_batch = o_rew + discount_factor * np.max(next_act,axis=-1) 
                    
                    train_loss, _ = sess.run( [loss, training_op],
                        feed_dict={X:np.array(o_obs,dtype=np.float), 
                                   y:np.expand_dims(
                                      np.array(y_batch,dtype=np.float),axis=-1), 
                                   X_action:np.array(o_act,dtype=np.int32), 
                                   in_training_mode:True } )

                
                if (global_step+1) % copy_steps == 0 and global_step > start_steps:
                    copy_target_to_main.run()
                    print('copy_target_to_main.run()')
                
                obs = next_obs
                epoch += 1
                global_step += 1
                episodic_reward += reward
            
            print('Episode', i, 'Reward', episodic_reward, 'epsilon', epsilonn,
                  'loss', train_loss )        
            
            if (i+1) % 100 == 0:            
                plt.plot(x_Data,y_Data)
                plt.show()
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided more information about the output, and what you've tried. For instance, have you used [The Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html), and if so what did it tell you?

Comment: It would be helpful if you isolated which lines of code are causing the problem. Otherwise you're asking others to carefully read through the entire script when the problem may just involve few lines or expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found out the problem in my simple program. I must normalize state vector and rewards. So the values must be in interval [-1, 1]. But I haven’t done this. When I do this my simple program starts working very well.